# Should I not be able to see deleted questions?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

With the current reputation associated with the privileges, and my current reputation, should I not be able to see deleted questions?

I know there was a question asked by chx here on meta, which has been deleted by him, but I cannot see it.
Did the privileges change, recently, and I am not allowed to see deleted questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see deleted questions by directly accessing the URL if you know that or by checking the recently deleted list in `/tools`. Only moderators can see deleted questions in a user profile.

Comment: I definitively got confused with what I could see as moderator.

Comment: Deleted questions are still listed in the "Flagging Summary" page too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can see it. But deleted questions doesn't show up in lists. Try the direct link https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-do-we-channel-people-back-to-drupal-org

Comment: @richardofc There's a rep requirement to view delete posts. It's 10k for normal sites and my guess is 5k for beta sites. This is why you cannot see it.